# How to prevent endless loop when loading data with React and Remix

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, remix.run

I have a web page that can have any number of chart components on it. Each of these components has its own selection boxes that allow the user to select two currencies. After a selection changes, the program gets data from a database for the exchange rate for the two currencies selected.

In **_index.tsx**, it just gets the list of currencies from the database and renders the HTML to create the select boxes. This seems to work fine.

In **chart.$type.$from.$to.tsx**, it allows the user to make selections for two currencies and respond to the selections by loading the data on a per-chart basis. The problem is that I have to `await` the call to `fetcher.load` and make the effect function `async`. But if I do that, I get an error that says `destroy is not a function`. But if I remove the asynchronous code, then `fetcher.data` remains undefined and I get no data.

I've never created a React or Remix application before and it is all totally new to me, so I have no idea if this is even even remotely close to the way it is supposed to be used or not. The reason I designed it this way is because it was going into an endless loop and I was trying to prevent that.

How do React/Remix developers get around these issues? All the examples I can find about getting data use functions that return hard-coded data, which is not a real-world scenario. In the real world, the data would come from a database or something, which requires an asynchronous call and that doesn't seem to work with hooks.

What kind of design would React/Remix developers use to make something like this work?

These are my two source files (with some imports removed to make the code shorter):

**_index.tsx**

```
import { db_client } from "./chartdata.server.tsx";
import { MyChart } from './chart.$type.$from.$to.tsx';

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
    const assets = await db_client.getAssets ();
    const response = json(assets);
    return response;
}

export default function Index() {
    const [charts, setCharts] = useState ([]);
    const [chartIdNum, setChartIdNum] = useState (1);

    const remChart = (deleteId) =>
    {
        setCharts ((charts) =>
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < charts.length; i++)
            {
                if (charts [i] === deleteId)
                    return charts.toSpliced (i, 1);
            }
        });
    };

    const addChart = () => {
        setCharts ((charts) => { return charts.concat (chartIdNum); });
        setChartIdNum ((chartIdNum) => { return chartIdNum + 1; });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={addChart}>Add Chart</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                {charts.map ((id) => { return (<MyChart key={id} id={id} remove={remChart} />); })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**chart.$type.$from.$to.tsx**

```
import { db_client } from "./chartdata.server.tsx";
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';

export async function loader({ params }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
    const prices = await db_client.getPrices (params.to, params.from);
    return json (prices);
}

export function MyChart ({id, remove})
{
    const fetcher = useFetcher();
    const [fromSelection, setFromSelection] = useState ('');
    const [toSelection, setToSelection] = useState ('');
    const [data, setData] = useState ([]);

    useEffect (
        async () =>
        {
            if (fromSelection.length > 0 && toSelection.length > 0)
            {
                if (data.length > 0)
                    setData ([]);

                let new_data = [["x", "low", "open", "close", "high"]];

                await fetcher.load ('/chart/' + 'candlestick' + '/' + fromSelection + '/' + toSelection);
//              for (let i = 0; i < fetcher.data.length; i++)
//                  new_data.push ([fetcher.data [i].period_begin, fetcher.data [i].low, fetcher.data [i].open, fetcher.data [i].close, fetcher.data [i].high]);

                if (JSON.stringify (data) !== JSON.stringify (new_data))
                    setData (new_data);
            }

        }, [fromSelection, toSelection, data]);

    async function handleCurrencySelected (e, curFrom)
    {
        if (curFrom && fromSelection != e.target.value)
            setFromSelection (e.target.value);
        else if (toSelection != e.target.value)
            setToSelection (e.target.value);
    }

    const options = { ... }; // omitting this because it is not causing the problem

    return (
        <div className="chart">

            <div>
                <button onClick={() => {remove (id);}}>Remove Chart</button>

                From:
                <select value={fromSelection} onChange={(e) => { handleCurrencySelected (e, true); }}>
                    <option key="empty" value=""></option>
                    {Object.keys (chartData).map ((k) => { return (<option key={k} value={k} disabled={toSelection !== null && toSelection == k}>{chartData [k]}</option>); })}
                </select>

                To:
                <select value={toSelection} onChange={(e) => { handleCurrencySelected (e, false); }}>
                    <option key="empty" value=""></option>
                    {Object.keys (chartData).map ((k) => { return (<option key={k} value={k} disabled={fromSelection !== null && fromSelection == k}>{chartData [k]}</option>); })}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>chart id: { id }</div>

            <div>
                <Chart
                    chartType="CandlestickChart"
                    width="100%"
                    height="350px"
                    data={data}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `fetcher.load()` is not async. Just call it then render your chart when `fetcher.data` is not undefined. You don’t need to call `useState`

Comment: The fetcher.load method in your MyChart component is asynchronous, and you're attempting to utilise await in the useEffect. But useEffect cannot be designated as async in and of itself. You can utilise a different async function inside useEffect in its place.
In the chart's loader function.Try-catch blocks can be used to manage problems and offer an alternate value or error message in $type.$from.$to.tsx.